# Reversing order of integration Graph and answer

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, graphing-functions

I am asked to reverse the order of integration an include a sketch of the region. I made a sketch in desmos for the purpose of this post.

The integral is

$$
\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{y-3}^{y^2} f(x, y) \ dx \ dy \\
D = \{ \ (x, y): \ \  y-3 \le x \le y^2, \ -1 \le y \le 1 \ \}
$$

I said the reverse would be:

$$
\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{x+3}^{\sqrt x} f(x, y) \ dy \ dx \\
D = \{ \ (x, y): \ \  x+3 \le y \le \sqrt x, \ -1 \le x \le 1 \ \}
$$

For my sketch:

[image: Pink is the shaded region of integration]

Am I right in saying this pink area is the region of integration?

Moreover, is my reverse correct?

Answer (score 0):

To reverse the integral, you must switch which variable varies from function to function and which variable varies from number to number, however upon inspecting this graph, you can see that there are actually 4 different functions that $y$ varies between:

1. On the interval $-4\leq{x}\leq-2$, the $y$ variable varies between $y=-1$ and $y=x+3$.
2. On the interval $-2\leq{x}\leq0$, the $y$ variable varies between $y=-1$ and $y=1$.
3. Finally, on the interval $0\leq{x}\leq1$, the $y$ variable varies between $y=\sqrt{x}$ and $y=1$, but **also** between $y=-1$ and $y=\sqrt{x}$.

Putting this all together, the new integral becomes:

$$\int_{-4}^{-2}\int_{-1}^{x+3} f(x,y)\ dy \ dx \ + \int_{-2}^{0}\int_{-1}^{1} f(x,y)\ dy \ dx \ + \int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_{\sqrt{x}}^{1} f(x,y)\ dy +\int_{-1}^{-\sqrt{x}} f(x,y)\ dy\right)\ dx$$

Comment: Can you expand the methods you used to come up with this? Points 1-3, all just seem like arbitrary intervals. How did you come up with them?